# An article before the word "Equation"

Tags: grammar, articles, science

In many scientific papers, the article before the word "Equation" is omitted. Is there any grammar statement behind this? For instance:

> "Equation (8) contains various approximations, and we have to check their consistency."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example refers to a specific equation, namely equation 8, therefore the equation eight or an equation eight would not really make sense in this case. An Equation y=x^2 however is a perfectly valid thing to say.

Comment: Thank you, but I can not understand why "the" is not valid? Does not a definite equation require the definite article?

Comment: Well, I suppose you could count 8 as an equation, but I'm guessing the 8 is referring to some equation somewhere? And I'm no English expert (it's not even my first language) so I don't have a grammatical reasoning for this, but the equation (8) feels a bit wonky. The point is it's not necessary in this context.

Comment: I have got your point. So, (8) can be considered as a demonstrative determiner, like this, those etc. I mean "equation (8)" can be replaced somehow by "that equation." And grammar tells us that the words with demonstrative determiners do not require an article.

Comment: It's the same as writing “In Section 2 we ...”.

Answer (score 2):

Try thinking of "Equation (8)" as the *name (identifier)* of the equation, just as your *name (identity)* is "freude".

You would expect someone to refer to you just by your name, as "freude" - you wouldn't expect them to refer to you as "the freude". Similarly, you refer to Equation (8) as "Equation (8)" because that is its *name*.

Answer (score 0):

The definitive article has its use when constructing an argument wherein a second / tertiary equation forms a lemma that contrasts other lemmas in the argument.

The definitive article can thus be used to create *contrast* between the facets of the argument.